# SSRS - IIF/Switch/Replace multiple conditions in a field

Tags: reporting-services, replace, switch-statement, iif, ssrs-expression

Have a nvarchar column in ms sql that, based on user input, may or may not have a carriage return and a line break together (CHR(13)&CHR(10)), just a carriage return (CHR(13)), just a line break (CHR(10)).  In using that column in ssrs, I need to find if any of the above exist and replace them with the string `\x0D\x0A`, `\x0D`, or `\x0A` respectively.

I'm getting lost in this expression, any help is appreciated.

```
=SWITCH
(
(InStr(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(13)&CHR(10) > 0, REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(13)&CHR(10)), "\x0D\x0A")),
(InStr(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(13) > 0, REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(13)), "\x0D")),
(InStr(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(10) > 0, REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(10)), "\x0A"))
)
```

Error is:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for
>   the textrun ‘Info.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error:
>   [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'Replacement' of
>   'Public Function Replace(Expression As String, Find As String,
>   Replacement As String, [Start As Integer = 1], [Count As Integer =
>   -1], [Compare As Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary]) As String'.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetReportDefinition(String
>   Report, Byte[] Definition, Guid batchId, Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.SetItemDefinition(String
>   ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, String expectedItemTypeName, Property[]
>   Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.SetItemDefinition(String
>   ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]&
>   Warnings)

Comment: `replace(replace(Fields!Info.Value,CHR(13),"\x0D"),CHR(10),"\x0A")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SWITCH(
InStr(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(13) & CHR(10)) > 0,
   REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value,CHR(13) & CHR(10), "\x0D\x0A"),
InStr(Fields!Info.Value,CHR(13)) > 0,
   REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(13), "\x0D"),
InStr(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(10)) > 0,
   REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value, CHR(10), "\x0A")
)
```

> Note if you use Switch function it will execute only the first case
>   that is `true`, so if the first condition is `true` the second and the
>   third will not be evaluated therefore not executed.

If you want to replace every char you should just use multiple `REPLACE` nested functions.

```
=Replace(
  Replace(
    REPLACE(Fields!Info.Value,CHR(13) & CHR(10), "\x0D\x0A"),
  CHR(13),"\x0D"),
CHR(10),"\x0A")
```